# iOS/autolayout/storyboard: Pin view not responsive for table header

Tags: ios, autolayout, tableview

Using storyboard, in the pin view of autloayout, when I try to pin the edges of a uiview that is a tableview headers i.e. the first subview of a tableview, the settings are all empty and the pin view is not responsive as shown:

file navigator:

[image]

pin view:

[image]

What do I have to do to pin the edges of the header view to their container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a view to a table view in that way, it *becomes* the table's HeaderView (or FooterView, if you put it at the bottom). The size and positioning of those views is controlled by the table.

It is the same case as with the cells... You'll notice if you select the `Cell` you will also see the blank "pin" view.

Comment: Ok.  That explains that and am marking it correct.  However, for some reason when the search bar is activated, the header ceases to be the same size as the tableview.  I was hoping to constraint it to the tableview.  I will ask another question about how to keep the header the same size as the tableview.